# ApplySymbologyFromLayer works in ArcMap but not in python script

Tags: arcgis-10.2, symbology, arcpy

So the ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management() tool doesn't seem to like me, at least when I try to use it in a script. I have a Field_Boundary2.lyr file that has a "hollow" fill color and a black outline for a polygon boundary. In ArcMap, when I import this layer's symbology onto another layer, it looks like this:

[image: hollow field boundary]

But if I try to use it with arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer() in a script, it gives me this:

[image: non-hollow field boundary]

Here's the code:

```
        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"dfElevation")[0]
        fc1 = arcpy.mapping.Layer(fcGrid)
        arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(fc1, arcpy.mapping.Layer(symbologyTemplatePath + "Elevation.lyr"))
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df,fc1,"BOTTOM")
        fc2 = arcpy.mapping.Layer(fcBound)
        arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(fc1, arcpy.mapping.Layer(symbologyTemplatePath + "Field_Boundary2.lyr"))
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df,fc2,"TOP")
```

From the picture above you can see that the "Elevation.lyr" symbology is being imported correctly, but not the "Field_Boundary2.lyr". Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Don't forget to save the map file: `mxd.save()`

Comment: Actually, it looks like your variable `fc1` should be `fc2` in line 6?

Comment: @EmilBrundage That's it! Thanks for catching that for me!

Comment: Cool, posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 6, change `fc1` to `fc2`.